# How can I access the Event object of a mousedown Vuejs event?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2

I have a Vue component (Vue 2.5) using typescript.

I have a @mousedown event which launch mouseDown function :

```html
<td
  v-for="hour in hours"
  @mousedown="mouseDown(day.index, hour, temperature_mode)"
  @mouseup="isMouseDown = false"
>
```

```js
mouseDown(day: number, hour: number, value: number) {
   this.isMouseDown = true;
   this.setScheduledTempMode(day, hour, value);
}
```

I want to access the event object of this event.

I tried something like this :

```js
mouseDown(e: Event, day: number, hour: number, value: number) {
   this.isMouseDown = true;
   this.setScheduledTempMode(day, hour, value);
   console.log(e);
}
```

But the log renders the day parameter value.

I tried also :

- change the type to "any" but I have the same result.
- move "e: Event" at the end of parameters, the result of the log is "undefined".

So how can I retrieve the event object?

Is this the type that is not good?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that contrary to vanilla JS, the event object is not added by default on any events.

So I have to use the special variable $event on my method call to access it.

I've changing this `@mousedown="mouseDown(day.index, hour, temperature_mode)"` to this `@mousedown="mouseDown(day.index, hour, temperature_mode, $event)"` and it I can access the event object now.

Doc:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers